# React email : require() of ES Module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I followed the react-email doc, and when I type the yarn email command I get this error:

```
$ email dev --port 3001
***\node_modules\ora\index.js:65
                if (process.platform === 'win32') {
                           ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ***\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js from ***\node_modules\ora\index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of ***\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js in ***\node_modules\ora\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at mod.require (***\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:65:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (***\Cutify\node_modules\ora\index.js:7:19)
    at mod.require (***\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:65:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (***\node_modules\react-email\cli\index.js:420:26) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

I tried to look at the doc or similar cases on issues but nothing relevant. If anyone has a solution

Answer (score 0):

I think this article might help.

```
const initEmailSystem = async () => {
if (process.platform === 'win32') {
await import('ora').then(oraPackage => {
  const ora = oraPackage.default;
  const spinner = ora('Initializing email system...').start();
  setTimeout(() => {
    spinner.succeed('Email system ready');
  }, 1000);
 });
} else {
console.log('Email system initialization skipped on non-Windows platform');
}
};
export default initEmailSystem;
```

[Solving the React-Email ES Module Requirement Issue](https://www.tempmail.us.com/en/python/solving-outlook-com-email-dispatch-error-in-python)